# Using .Htaccess url redirection

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I want to rewrite my url but i cant do proper way.

```
mysitename.net/index.php?title=Category:Public_Companies&pagefrom=8
```

To :

```
mysitename.net/Category:Public_Companies/8
```

How can i do that.

Answer (score 0):

If you have other pages than Category, I recommend to use this:

```
RewriteRule ^Category:(.+)/(.+)$ /index.php?title=Category:$1&pagefrom=$2 [L]
```

Otherwise, use this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)/(.+)$ /index.php?title=$1&pagefrom=$2 [L]
```

Comment: nothing to change brother. it cant affect my url. any other solutions?

Comment: @user3526554 Are you sure? This should work, I tested it [here](http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/). Did you put `RewriteEngine On` in the beginning of your .htaccess file?

Comment: can we remove "?title" from above URL?