# Remove Query string from website url

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

i want to remove query string from my url using htaccess but i cant find any proper solutions

www.mysite.net/index.php?title=Category:Public_Companies&redirect=no&pagefrom=GET+UP

I Want

www.mysite.net/Category:Public_Companies/GET+UP

How can i do this. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The fast and easy way 
.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*) index.php?title=$1&pagefrom=$2&redirect=no [L]
```

I create for all characters you need define what character you will be use.
Php file for test .htaccess frendly url

```
<?php print_r($_GET); ?>
```

Comment: I think that he wants it the other way around, from folders to parameters. (`remove query string`)

Comment: I think he duplicate question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23404495/using-htaccess-url-redirection

Comment: From 1 first question frendly url on my website
http://set4812.pl/test/Category:Public_Companies/8
And this question
http://set4812.pl/test/Category:Public_Companies/GET+UP
Do you have mod_rewrite on on your server?

Answer (score 0):

put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+index\.php\?title=([^\s&]+)&redirect=no&pagefrom=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2? [R=301,NE,L]

RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/?$ /index.php?title=$1&redirect=no&pagefrom=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: its not works for me brother.

Comment: What URL did you enter in your browser and what is location of this .htaccess file? Are there more rules too?

Comment: my .htaccess is placed in root of the project folder. and for url please see my question. in my  url in last parameter its dynamic like pagefrm or pageuntil.

Comment: If I ask a simple question then try to give straight answer. I have already read your question before answering. `root of the project folder` is vague term. Is it DocumentRoot or some subdirectory under it? Also what exact URL you see in your browser and what error you get. Provide as much detail as you can.